# Apply a filter inside a 'for...in' statement

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I apply a filter inside a ['for...in' statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)?

In other words, I want to iterate only some of the keys of an object.

It's pretty easy with a `for...of` statement, for example:

```
for (const key of Object.keys(obj).filter(key => key.startsWith("0x"))) {
    ...
}
```

But I want to use `for (const key in obj)` instead.

How can I apply a `filter` inside that statement?

Comment: That would require you to create a new object....

Comment: actually the `for-in` loop is used on different purpose. `for(const value in obj)`. I think you get my point.

Comment: @SifatHaque: No, I actually don't get your point. Would you mind to elaborate?

Comment: @SifatHaque No, a for-in loop iterates over the keys, not the values.

Comment: upss, i got that wrong. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 4):

Simply append an `if` statement after your `for(...)` expression:

```
for (const key in obj) if (key.startsWith("0x")) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No sure why you would want to do this, but you can use Object.fromEntries and Object.entries

```js
const obj = {
  '0x123': { hello: 1 },
  '0x124': { hello: 1 },
  '123': { hello: 1 },
}


const foo = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(arr => arr[0].startsWith("0x")));

for (const data in foo) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

Seems like just checking it inside the loop would make more sense

```js
const obj = {
  '0x123': { hello: 1 },
  '0x124': { hello: 1 },
  '123': { hello: 1 },
};

for (const data in obj) {
  if (!data.startsWith("0x")) continue;
  console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: I could also just use `for (const key of Object.keys(obj))` as I explained in my question, though I'm beginning to think that my goal wasn't properly clarified - I was hoping to avoid the `Object.keys` function, rather than avoiding the `of` operator, as might be interpreted from the question.

Comment: So to avoid it, you just do the check inside and if the key does not match, you skip that iteration.

Comment: Yeah, that's adding an `if` statement, I was hoping to use `filter` and make it "neater". Thanks anyway :)